# How can I prepend list items from a file to every line of another file as fast as possible in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, parallel-processing, xargs, data-processing

I'm trying to append a list of subdomains onto a list of domains using bash. I have 2 files, one has a list of domains, the other has a list of subdomains. The idea is that every line in file should be taken and have every line from file 2 prepended. I've provided examples below of the files, my current code and the expected data result.

The [subdomain file](https://github.com/cqsd/daily-commonspeak2/blob/master/wordlists/subdomains.txt) contains 150,000 items and the list of domains is only small, usually less than 50. The process takes over an hour, sometimes longer and I'd love to find a way to speed it up. I know that I can use xargs to create parallel commands and that may be an option however it took me a day or so of research to come up with this current solution and I don't have the know how to implement xargs in the loop, if thats even possible?

## file1

```
site.com
sub.site.com
sub1.site.com
sub.sub.site.com
```

## file2

```
admin
members
help
blog
```

## Current Solution

```
 while read -r F1; do
    while read -r F2; do
      echo "$F2.$F1"
    done < $file2 >> $fileOut
 done < $file1
```

## Expected Result ($fileOut)

```
admin.site.com
members.site.com
help.site.com
blog.site.com
admin.sub.site.com
members.sub.site.com
help.sub.site.com
blog.sub.site.com
admin.sub1.site.com
members.sub1.site.com
help.sub1.site.com
blog.sub1.site.com
admin.sub.sub.site.com
members.sub.sub.site.com
help.sub.sub.site.com
blog.sub.sub.site.com
```

Comment: Keeping the domains in memory should prevent swapping to that file during reading, and allow `>` i.o. `>>`.  If the order does not matter per subdomain applying the list of domains would be ideal. I have even used java to write such maintenance scripts, so one should not fear using programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using `awk`

```
awk 'NR<=FNR{a[NR]=$0} NR>FNR {for ( i in a) print a[i]"."$0}'  file2  file1
```

Demo:

```
$cat file1
site.com
sub.site.com
sub1.site.com
sub.sub.site.com
$cat file2 
admin
members
help
blog
$awk 'NR<=FNR{a[NR]=$0} NR>FNR {for ( i in a) print a[i]"."$0}'  file2  file1
blog.site.com
admin.site.com
members.site.com
help.site.com
blog.sub.site.com
admin.sub.site.com
members.sub.site.com
help.sub.site.com
blog.sub1.site.com
admin.sub1.site.com
members.sub1.site.com
help.sub1.site.com
blog.sub.sub.site.com
admin.sub.sub.site.com
members.sub.sub.site.com
help.sub.sub.site.com
$
```

Also read https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice

Comment: Especially thankful for the link, what a great resource. The speed difference is insane. There may be a faster way out there but this is so efficient that I'm going to mark as the answer.